# Newbie Question: How to add another method to a class in python, receiving TypeError

Tags: python, class, methods

Sort of new both to coding and here, so apologies for my ignorance, but I am trying to add a method to some code from codecademy to check if a grade is passing but I receive a TypeError each time and I am lost as to how to make the two types the same.

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self, name, year):
    self.name = name
    self.year = year
    self.grades = []
  def add_grade(self, grade):
    if type(grade) is Grade:
      self.grades.append(grade) 
   


roger = Student('Roger van der Weyden', 10)
sandro = Student('Sandro Botticelli', 12)
pieter = Student("Pieter Bruegel the Elder", 8)

class Grade:
  minimum_passing = 65
  def __init__(self, score):
    self.score = score
  def is_passing(score):
    if score >= 64:
      print("This grade is passing")
    else:
      print("This grade is failing")


pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
pieter_math = Grade(80)
pieter_math.is_passing()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `is_passing()` is called on the Grade instance, not on the `score` attribute.

So, this worked for me:

```
class Grade:
  minimum_passing = 65
  def __init__(self, score):
    self.score = score
  def is_passing(self):
    if self.score >= 64:
      print("This grade is passing")
    else:
      print("This grade is failing")
```

Comment: Many thanks!! I'm still getting used to classes.